# How to pass to the Converter Parameter something that is not hard coded

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, converters

Something like:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,Converter={StaticResource
  ccc},ConverterParameter=PersonName}"/>
```

when Person name is Property of the class for example.

**Update:**

I've seen a solution that tells to inherit from DependencyObject and to implement IValueConverter.
I want to know if there is something simpler.

Comment: Assuming the TextBlock is bound to `dataObject`., your example shows that you want the TextBlock.Text to equal some function of dataObject.Text and dataObject.PersonNametext field.  Does dataObject have a .Text property?  If not, use `{Binding PersonName...}.   If so, can you pass the whole dataObject in like this:  `{Binding Converter={StaticResource   ccc}}`?  Does do what you need?

Comment: @agent-j  The parameter that I want is from my window and not from the dataObject.

Comment: @Zahid Sattar is correct.  +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is straight-forward, but not what you want to hear.

You can only target a binding at DependencyProperty on a DependencyObject. Binding does not inherit from DO, so you can't binding the converter parameter.

If you want other state passed into a converter, you may have to subclass the desired obect and add new properties

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into MultiBinding?  If you want two properties sent to the converter, like "Text" and "PersonName" you may be able to do something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ccc}">
      <Binding Path="Text"/>
      <Binding Path="PersonName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

This assumes that "Text" and "PersonNames" are properties on the DataContext.  You may need to change the binding paths if that's not the case.