# How can I convert a complete object with IValueConverter in (Xamarin.Forms) XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, ivalueconverter

I have implemented the methods from IValueConverter in the class X.

```
public class X : IValueConverter {
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
       ...
 }
 ...
}
```

In XAML I have `<Label Text="{Binding A, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter=X}" />`

This works fine. The property A (from an instance of class Y) is passed to the Convert method in my instance of class X. And I can convert.

```
public class Y {
 public string A { get; set; }
 public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to pass the complete object to the Convert method. So if I can access property A and B from an instance of class Y within my convert method.

So I changed my XAML code to `<Label Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter=X}" />` But it didn't work. The parameter value in the Convert method is always null.

How can I pass the complete object (from type Y)? Or if it's not possible, how can I pass more than one property to the Convert method? In XAML.

Comment: Your code seems to be wrong... You cannot pass class `X` as converter parameter

Comment: Try to use multibinding... http://stackoverflow.com/a/6358345/4767498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Property` of `class Y`,

First you need to create a property of your class like below,

```
 public Y NewObject { get; set; }
```

Then you have to use your `NewObject` to bind like

```
<Label Text="{Binding NewObject, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}, ConverterParameter=X}" />
```

Now in your converter you will be able to get the object and get the `A` and `B` properties using the `NewObject`.